# using interface in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, interface

i'm new with kotlin , i got one problem with interface in kotlin , there is my interface

```
 interface Products{
    fun Succes(res:Product)
    fun Error(msg:String)
}
```

i used this interface in constructor  of some function like this

```
fun homeProducts(url: String, onRecived: Interfaces.Products){}
```

i did set value in this function ( homeProduct ) and i know its working fine , but problem is i cant imp this interface inside function

```
ServerCalls(this).homeProducts(url,onRecived = {
  // this is problem
    }  )
```

any idea's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions), like this:

```
ServerCalls(this).homeProducts(url, onRecived = object: Products {
        override fun Succes(res: Product) {
        }

        override fun Error(msg: String) {
        }
    })
```